# Create Flag using numpy.where with conditional logic against 4 columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to create a simple flag in my dataframe based on some conditional logic against a few columns

Here is my **Dataframe**:

```
+---------+---------+------------+------------+-----------------+
| Column1 | Column2 |   Date1    |   Date2    | Completed early |
+---------+---------+------------+------------+-----------------+
|       1 |       1 | 02/01/2020 | 01/01/2020 |               1 |
|       1 |       1 | 03/01/2020 | 03/01/2020 |               0 |
|       1 |       1 | 04/01/2020 | 05/01/2020 |               0 |
|       0 |       0 | 05/01/2020 | 04/01/2020 |               0 |
|       0 |       1 | 06/01/2020 | 01/01/2020 |               0 |
|       1 |       1 | 06/01/2020 | 02/01/2020 |               1 |
+---------+---------+------------+------------+-----------------+
```

What I want my code to say is:

If Column1 == 1 and Column2 == 1 then check if Date2 < Date1, if so give me a 1, else 0

I have tried this using numpy.where but can't get the syntax right:

```
df['Completed_Early'] = \
    np.where( ( (df.Column1 == 1) \
        & (df.Column2 == 1) ), \
            (df.Date2 < df.Date1), 1, 0)
```

*TypeError: where() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given*

Comment: replace `(df.Column2 == 1) ),` with `(df.Column2 == 1) ) &` ?

Comment: `df['Completed_Early'] = df.Date2.lt(df.Date1) & df['Column1'].eq(1) & df['Column2'].eq(1)`.

Comment: thank you @anky, 4 eyes are better than 2 :).

Comment: @QuangHoang I tried your suggestion but it got an error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'datetime.datetime'. However, Anky's solution fixed the issue. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

replaced (df.Column2 == 1) )**,** with (df.Column2 == 1) ) **&**

Answer (score -1):

Hi this code returns you what you are looking for:

```
      df[(df["C1"]==1)&(df["C2"]==1)&(df["Date1"]>df["Date2"])]
```

but you cannot create a new column with these values ​​because there is less element than in your dataframe. It is for this reason that you receive this error

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply @Raphaël Gervillié. Anky's solution worked :)